# Twilio: Available Numbers - How many numbers can I get?

Tags: c#, twilio

I want to get more than 200 available numbers in one country using Twilio API.
I'm using Twilio Sharp.
Currently I'm using the following staff.

```
var localAvailableNumbers = LocalResource.Read("US", pageSize: 200, limit: 1000);
```

The function has pageSize and limit parameter but they don't seem to work.

I also tried to calling this function several times

```
List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
while (numbers.Count < 200)
{
     var localAvailableNumbers = LocalResource.Read("US", pageSize: 200, limit: 1000);
     foreach (var num in localAvailableNumbers)
     {
          string str = num.PhoneNumber.ToString();
          if (numbers.IndexOf(str) < 0)
               numbers.Add(str);
          }
     }
}
MessageBox.Show(numbers.Count.ToString());
```

But it never ends and I can see only around 120 numbers are being added to the list and same numbers are being returned.

Has anyone ever met for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [available phone numbers endpoint](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/available-phone-numbers) doesn't have pagination, so you can't change the page size or get a next page. If you're interested in different numbers, you can [filter by area code, distance from a location, whether it contains certain numbers and many others listed in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/available-phone-numbers#local-get-basic-filters).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved the problem by filtering several area codes.

Comment: Glad to hear you're sorted!